# There're some new (at least 2010) review about QCD?

Tags: resource-recommendations, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement

I'll start my master's in the next semester and I'll study QCD. I want a review for learn QCD and know what's going on in this field. I more interested in confinement.

Comment: More on [QCD](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chromodynamics+resource-recommendations).

Comment: Sure, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2389. I think Prof. Skands is keeping it relatively up-to-date (last update July last year)

Answer (score 1):

See e.g., [Peter Skands' TASI lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2389), which are at the graduate-student level. Although first published in 2012, I think Prof. Skands is keeping them up-to-date (last update July last year).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the rather extensive review by S.Bethke, G.Dissertori and G.Salam (revised Sept. 2015) http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-qcd.pdf

It's rather broad in exploring both theoretical and experimental aspects, featuring a whistlestop tour of collider phenomenology and updates in precision measurements at the LHC and elsewhere. It also comes with an elaborate reference list that you can dip into to suit your needs.